# Assigning numbers to members of a list

Tags: c#, list, random

I need some ideas to implement in my project.
I need to assign a ticket number to persons on this list.

```
ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100001, "John", 914754123, "john@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100002, "Peter", 974123214, "peter@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100003, "Tidus", 941201456, "tidus@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100004, "Poppy", 987453210, "pops@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
```

Utente class is:

```
class Utente
{
    // Class Atributes

    private int numUtenteSaude;
    private String nome;
    private int telefone;
    private String email;
    private ConsoleColor color;





    public Utente(int numUtenteSaude, String nome, int telefone, String email, ConsoleColor color)
    {
        this.numUtenteSaude = numUtenteSaude;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.email = email;
        this.color = color;
    }



    public void display()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = this.color;
        Console.WriteLine("Pessoa: Numero Utente Saude: " + numUtenteSaude + " Telefone: " + telefone + "  " + "Nome:" + nome + " Email: " + email);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", numUtenteSaude, nome, telefone, email, color);
    }
}
```

This is like an hospital and the people on the list are arriving at the medical center. I need to assign a ticket number to people in the list.
How can I do this?

Comment: add a property ticket number? You're not telling us the problem at all

Comment: Perhaps just using a static int variable which is set initially to zero. Every time you create a Utente, you assign it the variable's value and increment it. That's as much as I could understand to answer from your question. As @EpicKip mentions, it's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: @HoriaComan I have a menu on my program. I need an entry like: "Assign Ticket to Utente" and it would assing a ticket number to the people on the list.

Comment: @EpicKip Yeah I though about that. Adding a ticketNumber property to utente but how can invocate it on the menu?

Comment: I don't understand your question.... 'how can I invocate it'

Comment: @EpicKip Imagine I need to randomly assign numbers from 1 to 20 to the persons on that list. What do I have to add on my Display method to do that?

Comment: @Dany4k But assigning random number in display method won't work as that method is for 1 instance of `Utente` they have no knowledge of each other

Comment: you also should have some checkbox list in either grid or list data control. And on menuitem click event filter out those checked ones and assign them ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the earlier comments (refer to the reference below), you want to be able to call the app to assign ticket to any `Utente` through an external action (i.e choose assign option on the menu). 
So I think you could create another class, then assign from there. For example:

```
    public class static UtenteMenuActions {
          private static int _currentTicketNumber = 0; 

          public static void Assign(Utente utente) {
               //assign to utente 
               _currentTicketNumber ++; 
          }

          public static void AssignAllUtentes(List<Utente> utenteList>) {
                foreach (Utente utente : utenteList) {
                       Assign(utente);
                }
          }
    }
```

My point is you need another layer outside the Utente class for all external actions(UI, etc..)stat on Utente. However, that's just my opinion.

Reference to comments:

> @HoriaComan I have a menu on my program. I need an entry like: "Assign Ticket to Utente" and it would assing a ticket number to the people on the list. – Dany4k 13 mins ago
>
> @EpicKip Yeah I though about that. Adding a ticketNumber property to utente but how can invocate it on the menu? – Dany4k 11 mins ago

Comment: Thanks, that is a really good sugestion, gonna give it a try. Thank you.